# Load QPixmap from QByteArray in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qpixmap, qbytearray

I have a byte array with the contents of an image (in png/bmp or some other format).

How can I load it into a QPixmap?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
bool QPixmap::loadFromData ( const QByteArray & data, const char * format = 0, Qt::ImageConversionFlags flags = Qt::AutoColor )
```

Format here is string literal like `"PNG"` or something similar

```
QPixmap p;
QByteArray pData;
// fill array with image
if(p.loadFromData(pData,"PNG"))
{
   // do something with pixmap
}
```

Comment: @raive : can you pls add a simple example ?

Comment: BYTE* pData;
QByteArray pArray;
     pArray.append((const char*) pData);

     m_pixmap.loadFromData(pArray,"PNG");
     m_pixmap.save((QString("./Test.png"), "PNG")); I am using this code but it seems to be not working.

Comment: Well, it depends from what you have in pdata. code is correct.

Comment: I saw two other your questions - about QByteArray and about the non-gui thread... trouble is probably there. And answers you received are correct - use QImage and provide size for your data loaded from byte*

Answer (score 7):

You should use the folowing, where your bytes are in the imageData variable in the format specified by the last parameter:

```
QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(
    QImage(
        (unsigned char *) imageData, 
        image_width, 
        image_height, 
        QImage::Format_RGB888
    )
);
```

Comment: True, you can find the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854290/it-is-not-safe-to-use-pixmaps-outside-the-gui-thread-in-qt-embedded-linux)

Answer (score 0):

Use this constructor:

```
QImage ( const uchar * data, int width, int height, Format format )
```

[Here is more info](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qimage.html#image-formats). After that, you can use `QPixmap.convertFromImage()` to create a pixmap.

Comment: i want to convert from byte array to Image ,but QImage takes first parameter as const uchar* not byte array )

Comment: `uchar` is a byte. Just use a cast.