# It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI Thread in QT Embedded linux

Tags: qt

I am facing one issue

"It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI Thread" in QT Embedded linux
"Cannot set parent, new parent is in different thread"

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QPixmap is display-dependent is designed and optimized for showing images on screen.

It accesses the underlying graphics system. Most graphics systems are not thread-safe. So hence the warning.

Try using QImage.

Answer (score 0):

Since the screen is a device, only one thread at a time can access it for display. Qt has designated their "GUI Thread" to be the only one to do this.

QObjects, such as QWidgets, are associated with the thread that created them to keep track of all this. If a heirarchy of objects are associated with one thread, and you try to change the parent to an object in a different thread then there is a problem... it can't be allowed since the children may be dependent on that particular thread to work.

Eg. If the parent of an object has already been set, you cannot use moveToThread(object);