# Fast convert from Byte Array to image, that QT can show in form

Tags: c++, arrays, image, qt

So i have a camera over ethernet. In SDK there are event OnNewFrame(int lPicFormat, int lWidth, int lHeight, int lDataSize, QVariant &pvData), where pvData is interesting array of image bytes. So, i need to convert this array to QT understanding format and show in form(for example in label). Can anybody help me?

Comment: Take a look at QPixmap::loadFromData  like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826683/load-qpixmap-from-qbytearray-in-qt

Comment: @duDE function QPixmap::loadFromData returns false. I think, it's because my pvData array hasn't any headers. It's usual array of bits/pixel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QImage provide several constructor Look at http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qimage.html#QImage-6. 
Then you can use the QPixmap::fromImage method http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html#fromImage to convert the image to a QPixmap and set to a QLabel

Answer (score 1):

Display your array into a label

```
QByteArray mByteArray;
QPixmap mPixmap;
mPixmap.loadFromData(mByteArray,"JPG");
ui->label->setPixmap(mPixmap);
```

and check what `mpixmap.loadFromData(data,"JPG");` returns. If it returns false then it could not load your data.
If you want to display QByteArray as image, look at this:  [How to display a QByteArray as an Image](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/1594-How-to-display-a-QByteArray-as-an-Image)

Comment: there's no headers in my array. Yes, i want to display QByteArray. There are no thread in your link.